# How to launch a OneSignal prompt while using ionic?

Tags: ionic4, onesignal

The OneSignal site goes through great detail on launching the prompt for browsers, but I'm either overlooking the option for mobile or that option doesn't exist.

I'm using Ionic 4/Angular 8 with the cordova-onesignal plugin. I've tried `OneSignal.showNativePrompt()` but that method doesn't exist on OneSignal. I've also tried `this.oneSignal` just to see what functions are available and read the comments, but there doesn't seem to be anything that triggers the prompt.

Is there some other way using Ionic to trigger the message to allow users to subscribe to notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind!

Guess I overlooked the `promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse()` function. Looks like it is a promise so you can perform your full suite of setup after it resolves.